# Modeling tabular structure in MSSQL to store data like Excel sheet applying Column inheritance

Tags: performance, sql, recursion, sql-server, t-sql

I've created this database structure to store tabular information (it's a simplification of my real structure but enough to show the point). In it I have `Sheet`s and each Sheet can define different `Column`s. The important part is that with this structure I can define different datatypes for each `Column`.

Those could be divided in two groups: `Natives` (defined in the `Native_Types` table) and `SheetType` from the already created `Sheets`.

[image: Model structure]

#### Code to get unpivoted data:

```
CREATE VIEW RowsData
AS
    SELECT r.ID, s.ID SheetID, col.ID ColID, 
            col.Name, ISNULL(clsVal.NativeValue, cls.NativeValue) NativeValue
    FROM Sheets s
        INNER JOIN [Columns] col ON s.ID = col.SheetID
        INNER JOIN [Rows] r ON s.ID = r.SheetID
        INNER JOIN Cells cls ON r.ID = cls.RowID AND col.ID = cls.ColumnID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rows] rType ON cls.RowValueID = rType.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Sheets sType ON rType.SheetID = sType.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Cells clsVal ON rType.ID = clsVal.RowID AND sType.WhenIsTypeShowThisColumnIDValue = clsVal.ColumnID
GO
```

#### Sample data:

```
ID          SheetID     ColID       Name               NativeValue
----------- ----------- ----------- ------------------ ------------
1           1           1           Person Name        Aron
1           1           2           Person Country     Uruguay
2           1           1           Person Name        Sam
3           2           4           Country Name       Uruguay
4           2           4           Country Name       USA
5           2           4           Country Name       Russia
6           3           5           Pet Name           Mickey
6           3           6           Pet Age            83
6           3           7           Pet Person Owner   Aron
7           3           5           Pet Name           Pluto
7           3           6           Pet Age            8
7           3           7           Pet Person Owner   Aron
8           3           5           Pet Name           Zabivaka
8           3           6           Pet Age            4
8           3           7           Pet Person Owner   Sam
```

From here is all ok and any suggestion if there is a better way or any 
 improvements are welcome!

---

### Weird stuff begins

Then I've implemented some kind of inheritance over `Column`s and its `Cell`s.
For instance defining new `Column` for Sheet 3 (Pets) called "Pet Country"  (setting it `SheetTypeID` -> 2, Countries). Now `Pets` have a `Column` "Pet Country" but instead of define a `Cell` value for each one if I define this `Column` as inherited (and particular structure to support in which way) I could inherit the `Country` value from "Pet Owner". Remember that "Pet Owner" is of `SheetTypeID` 1 (`Persons`) and this Sheet have a Column of `SheetTypeID` 2 (`Countries`).

By simplifying I mean that if I have a `Pet` that has a Column "Pet Owner" and "Pet Country," I don't want to specify manually the "Pet Country" value, I want to inherit it from "Pet Owner" related with each `Pet`.

To accomplish that I have added two auxiliary fields to Columns table:

- `ColumnSameSheetInheritFromID` -> This defines from which Column of the same Sheet this `Column` must inherit (must be Sheet type Column).
- `ColumnRelatedToFromColumnTypeID` -> This defines from which Column of the Sheet type of the above `Column` must this `Campo` get the real inherited `Cell` value then.

Adjusted diagram:

[image: Adjusted diagram]

---

**Helper self referenced function to get inherited Cells from Columns
(here is where I presume should be a better way to do things)**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetInheritedCells](@rowID INT, @colID INT)
RETURNS @result TABLE (ID INT)
AS
BEGIN   

    DECLARE @ColumnSameSheetInheritFromID INT = NULL;
    DECLARE @ColumnRelatedToFromColumnTypeID INT = NULL;

    --GETTING COLUMN FROM AND COLUMN VALUE IDs
    SELECT @ColumnSameSheetInheritFromID = col.ColumnSameSheetInheritFromID,
           @ColumnRelatedToFromColumnTypeID = col.ColumnRelatedToFromColumnTypeID  
    FROM dbo.[Columns] col
    WHERE col.ID = @colID;

    --IF COLUMN IS NOT INHERITED FUNCTION ENDS
    IF @ColumnSameSheetInheritFromID IS NULL OR @ColumnRelatedToFromColumnTypeID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        RETURN;
    END

    DECLARE @cellFromID INT = NULL;
    DECLARE @cellInhValueID INT = NULL;
    DECLARE @colFromAUX_ID INT = NULL;

    DECLARE @cellHaveValue INT = NULL;

    --GETTING REF FROM ROW RELATED TO THE RESPECTIVE DATA OF INHERITED COLUMN FROM AND CURRENT ROW              
    SELECT @cellFromID = cls.ID, 
           @colFromAUX_ID = col.ColumnSameSheetInheritFromID,
           @cellHaveValue = IIF(cls.RowValueID IS NULL, 0, 1)

        FROM dbo.[Rows] r
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Columns] col
                ON r.SheetID = col.SheetID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Cells] cls
                ON r.ID = cls.RowID AND col.ID = cls.ColumnID
    WHERE r.ID = @rowID AND col.ID = @ColumnSameSheetInheritFromID

    IF @cellHaveValue = 0 AND @colFromAUX_ID IS NOT NULL
        SET @cellFromID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM dbo.GetInheritedCells(@rowID, @ColumnSameSheetInheritFromID));
    ELSE IF @cellFromID IS NULL AND @ColumnSameSheetInheritFromID IS NULL
        SET @cellFromID = -1;

    IF @cellFromID > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @rowID = cls.RowValueID
        FROM dbo.[Cells] cls INNER JOIN dbo.[Columns] col ON cls.ColumnID = col.ID
        WHERE cls.ID = @cellFromID;

        IF @rowID IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            --GETTING REF FROM ROW RELATED TO THE RESPECTIVE DATA OF INHERITED COLUMN FROM AND CURRENT ROW              
            SELECT @cellInhValueID = cls.ID, 
                   @colFromAUX_ID = col.ColumnSameSheetInheritFromID,
                   @cellHaveValue = (IIF(cls.RowValueID IS NULL, IIF(cls.NativeValue IS NULL, 0, 1),1))

                FROM dbo.[Rows] r
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Columns] col
                        ON r.SheetID = col.SheetID
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Cells] cls  
                        ON r.ID = cls.RowID AND col.ID = cls.ColumnID
            WHERE r.ID = @rowID AND col.ID = @ColumnRelatedToFromColumnTypeID

            IF @cellHaveValue = 0 AND @colFromAUX_ID IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @result SELECT ID FROM dbo.GetInheritedCells(@rowID, @ColumnRelatedToFromColumnTypeID);
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @result SELECT cls.ID
                FROM dbo.[Rows] r
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Columns] col
                        ON r.SheetID = col.SheetID
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Cells] cls  
                        ON r.ID = cls.RowID AND col.ID = cls.ColumnID
                WHERE r.ID = @rowID AND col.ID = @ColumnRelatedToFromColumnTypeID;
            END
        END
    END 

    RETURN;
END
```

Updated RowsData view:

```
ALTER VIEW RowsData
AS
    SELECT r.ID, s.ID SheetID, col.ID ColID, /*Columns Added*/col.ColumnSameSheetInheritFromID, col.ColumnRelatedToFromColumnTypeID,
            col.Name, ISNULL(clsVal.NativeValue, cls.NativeValue) NativeValue
    FROM Sheets s
        INNER JOIN [Columns] col ON s.ID = col.SheetID
        INNER JOIN [Rows] r ON s.ID = r.SheetID
        /*OUTER APPLY added*/
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT ID FROM dbo.GetInheritedCells(r.ID, col.ID)) inhCel
        LEFT JOIN Cells cls ON r.ID = cls.RowID AND col.ID = cls.ColumnID /* This added -> */ OR inhCel.ID = cls.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Rows] rType ON cls.RowValueID = rType.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Sheets sType ON rType.SheetID = sType.ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Cells clsVal ON rType.ID = clsVal.RowID AND sType.WhenIsTypeShowThisColumnIDValue = clsVal.ColumnID
GO
```

Resultant data example:

```
ID          SheetID     ColID       ColumnSameSheetInheritFromID ColumnRelatedToFromColumnTypeID Name                                               NativeValue
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------------------- ------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------------
1           1           1           NULL                         NULL                            Person Name                                        Aron
1           1           2           NULL                         NULL                            Person Country                                     Uruguay
2           1           1           NULL                         NULL                            Person Name                                        Sam
2           1           2           NULL                         NULL                            Person Country                                     NULL
3           2           4           NULL                         NULL                            Country Name                                       Uruguay
4           2           4           NULL                         NULL                            Country Name                                       USA
5           2           4           NULL                         NULL                            Country Name                                       Russia
6           3           5           NULL                         NULL                            Pet Name                                           Mickey
6           3           6           NULL                         NULL                            Pet Age                                            83
6           3           7           NULL                         NULL                            Pet Person Owner                                   Aron
6           3           8           7                            2                               Pet Country                                        Uruguay
7           3           5           NULL                         NULL                            Pet Name                                           Pluto
7           3           6           NULL                         NULL                            Pet Age                                            8
7           3           7           NULL                         NULL                            Pet Person Owner                                   Aron
7           3           8           7                            2                               Pet Country                                        Uruguay
8           3           5           NULL                         NULL                            Pet Name                                           Zabivaka
8           3           6           NULL                         NULL                            Pet Age                                            4
8           3           7           NULL                         NULL                            Pet Person Owner                                   Sam
8           3           8           7                            2                               Pet Country                                        NULL
```

**[Database script with example data to play with here!](https://gist.github.com/gsubiran/892d438cb1e432400ce44c9e0e111922)**

Thanks to [dfhwze](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/200620/dfhwze) who was created [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=adb2088385d70ee4a9c1cc7a92decc52) to play with!

Comment: Hey I wish somebody would supply an answer but that might not happen anytime soon... I see you are a member of the [DBA SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) and your post [appears to be on topic there](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) so maybe that would give you better responses (perhaps from people like [@Brent Ozar](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/426/brent-ozar) or the like).

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ to migrate the question to DBA SE, should I need to delete it from here right?

Comment: Not necessarily... I think you could leave it here in case somebody decides to review the queries, etc.

Comment: I'll have a go with this one and play around with it this weekend, hopefully resulting in a meaningful review.

Comment: You could already have a look here and see if this would be helpful or not: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959804/simulation-of-connect-by-prior-of-oracle-in-sql-server.

Comment: @dfhwze yes! I'm trying to do a recursive CTE but no luck. I'm weird cause is not a simple recursion, you have to take care about two Columns (`ColumnSameSheetInheritFromID`, `ColumnRelatedToFromColumnTypeID`) ,  for each inherited Column

Comment: Here is a fiddle to play with for anyone interested in testing the sql: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=adb2088385d70ee4a9c1cc7a92decc52. You can add the link in the question if you want.

Comment: Is there a reason that you aren't just making tables to hold all of these? Why do you need to re-create table metadata?

Comment: @Dannnno with this architecture the schema is dynamic. If I create tables I will lost this ability. At the starting point I don't know Sheets and Columns structure